# Execute immediate select statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using execute immediate statement in one of my queries.

```
    procedure p1 (p_pk1_column, p_pk2_column , p_conv_table_name ,p_MODUE_NAME )
    is
    v_select_string   := 'SELECT'''||p_MODUE_NAME||''',''' ||p_pk1_column || ''',''' || p_pk2_column ||''' FROM ' ||p_conv_table_name || v_where_condition;
    execute immediate v_select_string  ;
    dbms_output.put_line('string:'||v_select_string  );
    end p1;
```

Here I am calling p1 procedure in another procedure p2

```
PROCEDURE P2 IS
v_pk1_column:='a';
v_pk2_columnm:='b';
v_mod_name:='mOD1';
p1(v_pk1_column,v_pk2_columnm);
end p2;
/
```

In p2 procedure a, b are the column names of p_conv_table_name . I want to execute the select statement like select p_mod_name, a, b from p_conv_table_name where condition; so that it should give values for a and b columns in p_conv_table_name .

But it is executing like select p_mod, p_pk1_col,p_pk2_col from p_conv_table_name where condition;

So simply column names are selecting instead of values in that column.

Please suggest some approach to achieve values in that column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like too many single quotes to me?  Instead of "SELECT a, b," etc. you are executing "SELECT 'a', 'b'," etc.

Comment: Just check script's output and you find it's like `SELECT'z','zz','zzz' FROM zzzz`. And it's a good practice to supply a question with syntactic-correct examples

Comment: Why don't you want to use neither DBMS_SQL package nor bind variables? It is possible to get a SQL injection when you build your dynamic query like this, `DBMS_SQL` and bind variables help you to avoid it.

Comment: As [per the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1205); if you're executing a SELECT statement you need to SELECT _INTO_ something...

Answer (score 3):

When the `SELECT` statement is built the column names are surrounded in single-quotes, which turns them into string literals. Change your procedure to something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1 (p_pk1_column      IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_pk2_column      IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_conv_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_MODUE_NAME      IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_select_string    VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_where_condition  VARCHAR2(2000) := ' WHERE SOMETHING = SOMETHING_ELSE';
  csr                SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_val_1            VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_val_2            VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_mod_name         VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  v_select_string   := 'SELECT ' || p_MODUE_NAME || ',' ||
                                    p_pk1_column || ',' ||
                                    p_pk2_column ||
                       ' FROM ' || p_conv_table_name ||
                       v_where_condition;

  dbms_output.put_line('string:' || v_select_string);

  OPEN csr FOR v_select_string;

  LOOP
    FETCH csr INTO v_mod_name, v_val_1, v_val_2;

    EXIT WHEN csr%NOTFOUND;         

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_mod_name=''' || v_mod_name || '''  ' ||
                         'v_val_1=''' || v_val_1 || '''  ' ||
                         'v_val_2=''' || v_val_2 || '''');
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csr;
END P1;
```

I've also changed the code to `OPEN` and `FETCH` a cursor rather than using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. `OPEN` and `FETCH` are generally more appropriate for use with a dynamic `SELECT` statement.

Share and enjoy.