# how to execute immediate sql string to shows result direcly?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, execute-immediate, dbms-output

I'm trying to execute sql string be executed like this image1

[image: screenshot]

but. when I execute immediate my sql string, it doesn't return to any output like the first one.
how can I make it return the output without pass the output into a variable? please help

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990913/execute-immediate-select-statement-in-oracle

Comment: thanks. for case the column is dynamic, how can I execute immediate and print the result?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in 12c, try `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` using a `REFCURSOR` over any dynamic query.

```
DECLARE
     sqlstring   VARCHAR2(2000);
     cur         SYS_REFCURSOR;
     tab_name    VARCHAR2(100) := 'YOUR_TAB_NAME';
     col_name    VARCHAR2(32)  := 'COL_NAME';
     n           INT := 5;
     m           INT := 10;
BEGIN
     sqlstring :=   'SELECT '||col_name||',col1,col2,col3 FROM ' || tab_name  
               || ' OFFSET ' || n || ' ROWS FETCH NEXT '
                             || m || ' ROWS ONLY ';
     OPEN cur FOR sqlstring;
     dbms_sql.return_result(cur);
END;
/
```